# Select option from svg element selenium vba

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

I have an element to choose nationality from it. This is the outer HTML

```
<div class="base-select-control-wrapper"><div class="mobile-select-open"></div><div class="base-select-control"><span class="base-select-control__label">Nationality</span><input type="text" class="base-select-control__input" mousedown.prevent="" style="display: none;"><div class="base-select-control__input" role="combobox" style=""></div><!----><svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="base-select-control__icon" icon="arrow"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M5.29289 8.29289C5.68342 7.90237 6.31658 7.90237 6.70711 8.29289L12 13.5858L17.2929 8.29289C17.6834 7.90237 18.3166 7.90237 18.7071 8.29289C19.0976 8.68342 19.0976 9.31658 18.7071 9.70711L12.7071 15.7071C12.3166 16.0976 11.6834 16.0976 11.2929 15.7071L5.29289 9.70711C4.90237 9.31658 4.90237 8.68342 5.29289 8.29289Z" fill="#778A99" fill-opacity="0.8"></path></svg></div></div>
```

How can I select any country from this element? I tried even to click the element (as a simulation but could not do it at all).

This is my try but raises an error when used in the code (vba selenium in excel)

```
//span[contains(text(), 'Nationality') and @class='base-select-control__label']
```

When click on the element manually, I can inspect the options but they are away from the element and this is the outer HTML of the options

```
<ul class="base-select-options"><li class="base-select__option" data-id="004"><img data-v-410fcf0a="" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACwAAAAeCAYAAABXNqCcxnCHhBAmMZAv5aAkeAegZg68ARBZSB7cA7wDBgVhhoA/gGeA8o3x4A3YIaax6vgRkAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" class="country-flag"> Afghanistan</li>
```

To make the question more clearer, I will provide the link:
follow this url https://qic.online/en/visitors then click Buy Policy then select any date and proceed then select any duration then you will find the element of Nationality

I have used this line of code

```
Set objOptions = .FindElementsByXPath("//div[@class='mobile-select-open']")
```

then referred to the first element of the two in the page by `objOptions(1)` but couldn't use `SendKeys` method.

Based on Yaroslavm's answer I have used these lines

```
sNationality = Cells(iRow, "N").Value
.FindElementByCss("[class*=nationalities]").Click
.FindElementByXPath("//*[@class='base-select-options']//*[contains(.,'" & sNationality & "')]").Click
```

It works but there is a problem when `sNationality` equals to `INDIA`, I got `BRITISH INDIAN OCEAN`. How can I solve this point?

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide site or whole HTML structure, so we are able to help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case first you should click on dropdown and then select needed option from list.

Here is code in Java, I think you can easily re-write it to VB.

```java
WebDriverWait wdwait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

// you are placed on page Fill Personal Information

wdwait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(new By.ByCssSelector("[class*=nationalities]"))).click();
wdwait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(new By.ByXPath(constructCountrySelector("Albania")))).click();

...

String constructCountrySelector(String country) {
   return String.format("//*[@class='base-select-options']//*[contains(.,'%s')]", country);
}
```

This solution works for me.
If you need help in re-writing this code to VB, lmk.

if you need strict equal,

```js
String constructCountrySelector(String country) {
   return String.format("//*[@class='base-select-options']//*[text()=' %s']", country);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. you saved my day. There is just one note posted in the main question.

Comment: @YasserKhalil in your case strict equal selector is `//*[@class='base-select-options']//*[text()=' %s']` (updated answer)

Comment: I tried that but got an error NoSuchElementError.

Comment: I works for me. Have you defined space before '%s'? On your site text of dropdown element contain space in the beginning

Comment: I am not sure. I have added space `.FindElementByXPath("//*[@class='base-select-options']//*[contains(.,' " & sNationality & "')]").Click` but the same problem.

Comment: `Function ConstructCountrySelector(ByVal country As String) As String
    Return String.Format("//*[@class='base-select-options']//*[text()=' {0}']", country)
End Function`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254817/discussion-between-yaroslavm-and-yasserkhalil).